# Can I port forward to an established reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have three computers, A, B and C. A has initiated a reverse ssh tunnel to B.

```
ssh  -nTNx -p 443 -R 22222:localhost:22 [user]@[server]
```

If I log in to B, I can use 'ssh -p 22222 localhost' and I get a login prompt for A.
If I try 'ssh -p 22222 [public IP of B]', it doesn't work

What I would like to be able to do is have C connect to A without needing to login to B. So from C I could 'ssh -p 22222 [public IP of B]' and I would get the login prompt for A.

I am using debian and shorewall and I have a basic understanding of how things work. I have tried various combinations of REDIRECT and DNAT rules, but haven't had any luck. I have tried using the same port (22222) and a different port (forwarding 22223 from C to 22222 on localhost).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "Remote port forwarding for anyone at work !" section of [this webpage](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html).  The article suggests that you should add the

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

option to your `sshd_config` on your HostB.  That should cause the remote port forwarding on your HostB to listen on all of its network interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `-g` flag in your ssh command? That's what tells it to allow remote systems to connect to local ports. So you'd do something like:

```
hostB$ ssh -g -L22222:localhost:22 user@hostA
```

Then from host C, this should work:

```
hostC$ ssh -p22222 user@hostB
```